# How to get gender voice from URL parameter in google text to speech API in PHP?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-text-to-speech

I have build the text to speech api in php using google cloud. I am able to pass other parameters such as pitch, speaking rate, text from URL parameter but I just want to know how I can do the same for gender voice?

I have tried passing it as string or passing the whole argument but none of these work.

```
$synthesisInputText = (new SynthesisInput())->setText($_GET['text']);

            $voice = (new VoiceSelectionParams())
                ->setLanguageCode($_GET['lang']))
                // ->setName('en-IN-Wavenet-A')
                ->setSsmlGender(SsmlVoiceGender::FEMALE);

            $audioConfig = (new AudioConfig())
                ->setAudioEncoding(AudioEncoding::MP3)
                ->setPitch($_GET['pitch'])
                ->setSpeakingRate($_GET['speking_rate']);

            $response = $this->client->synthesizeSpeech($synthesisInputText, $voice, $audioConfig);

            $audioContent = $response->getAudioContent();

            file_put_contents($this->file,$audioContent);
```

I am able to get all other parameters correctly but I want get `setSsmlGender(SsmlVoiceGender::$_GET['voice'])` from URL parameter as well. Any help would be great?

Comment: Maybe pass in an encoding that you use as an expression.  For example MALE -> SsmlVoiceGender::MALE  and FEMALE -> SsmlVoiceGender::FEMALE.  Sadly, I don't speak PHP but I assume one can code expressions to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`SsmlVoiceGender::value()`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-text-to-speech/blob/b6a1d9ea4e5fef85e6033e8b0b44c66462aaf490/src/V1/SsmlVoiceGender.php#L63) method to convert your input to the proper enum value:

```
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\SsmlVoiceGender;

$genderInput = $_GET['voice'];
try {
    $gender = SsmlVoiceGender::value($genderInput);
} catch (\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
    // Invalid input. Hardcode a value?
    $gender = SsmlVoiceGender::MALE;
}

$voice->setSsmlGender($gender);
```

Make sure you are using `google/cloud-voice-text-to-speech` v0.4.0 or higher. If you're using `google/cloud`, be sure to use `v0.98.0` or higher.